GNU radio create custom source
I want to implement the signal $$x(t)=4\cos2t+5\sin30t+5$$ $$0<=t<1$$
GNU Radio has source blocks:

but the waveform is continuous over time,I want it to start at $t=0$ and end at $t=1$. What should I do?

Welcome to SE.SP!  I'm not strong on GNU Radio, but the head block seems to do something like what you're asking.
